# MP4 video request getting modified and header changed by something

Tags: c#, http, xamarin, video-streaming

I'm using a Webview in Xamarin to pull up a video address.  Similarly happens in Edge/Chrome.  I add some header token security info using a customversion of webview so calling it like the following:

```
<local:custwebview Source="http://example.com/myvideo.mp4" />
```

My restful API gets the request and after I validate security token reply back with:

```
return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, mimeType);
```

Then some mysterious back and forth happens, because my restful service gets another request (which doesnt have my security anymore), but has a list of headers including referer:
[image]

And then the webview/browser ends up with extra html as follows:

> ```
> <html><head>
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
> </head>
> <body>
>     <div>
>         <video width="320" height="240" controls="" autoplay="autoplay">
>             <source src="https://example.com/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
>         </video>
>     </div>
> </body></html>
> ```

So who inserted all that html? and how can I control that like changing autoplay, and adding back in my token?  I've tried to track using fiddler and postman but I can't figure out who is adding all that html and forcing the reload after it in the webview/browser.  Regular Edge/Chrome does the similar thing, so I'm thinking my restful API must be doing it, but I don't see how.

Comment: what does the value of the referer heading get set to?  Have you looked using the dev tools on the desktop browser to see what is happening?

Comment: Referer is set to my original http://example.com/myvideo.mp4   .  Not sure what the dev tools on desktop browser means, I've inspected to see the html, but doesn't give me a back and forth log that I can see.

Comment: It looks like the browser is making range requests for specific sections of the file.

Comment: almost all browsers have a dev console built in that you can use to examine network requests, redirects, etc